# Is the optimal solution of a convex problem continuous with respect to parameters?

Tags: continuity, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Given the convex problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N} f(x_i)\\ \text{subject to} & Ax = B\\ & 0\leq x_{\min} \leq x_i \leq x_{\max}\end{array}$$

where $f$ is convex, $A \in \mathcal{R}^{M \times N}$ has full row rank, and $N>M$. Let the solution of the problem above be denoted by $x^*$. Also, let the equality condition depend on parameters $a$ and $b$,

$$A(a)x = B(b)$$

If $A(a)$ and $B(b)$ are continuous in $a$ and $b$, is $x^*(a,b)$ also continuous in $a$ and $b$?

Comment: You're implicitly assuming that the solution will be unique, but your hypotheses don't ensure that.

Comment: I should have written $f(x_i)$ is strictly convex.  If so, is not the whole problem strictly convex, and there is only one unique minimum, or am I missing something?.

Comment: My comment was simply that $f(x)$ could have been convex but not strictly convex in your original formulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, locally, at least if the problem is strongly convex. Strict convexity may also suffice, but I am not sure about this.

If $f(x)$, $A(a)$, and $B(b)$ were smooth and there were no box constraint, then the result follows from applying the implicit function theorem to the condition that the gradient of the Lagrangian for the problem, $\mathcal{L}$, equals zero (which is the local condition for optimality). You can even get a formula for the tangent vector. Specifically, for $(x^*, \lambda^*)$ to be a solution to the problem, we must have
$$
0 = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where these quantities are evaluated at the point $(x^*, \lambda^*)$. Differentiating this equation with respect to $a$ yields
$$
0 = \frac{d}{da} \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial x^2} \\
\frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial x^2}
\end{bmatrix}}_{\nabla^2 \mathcal{L}}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{dx^*}{da} \\ \frac{d\lambda^*}{da}
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial x \partial a} \\
\frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda \partial a}
\end{bmatrix},$$
and you can solve this linear system to determine the tangent vectors $\frac{dx^*}{da}$ and $\frac{d\lambda^*}{da}$. The coefficient matrix $\nabla^2 \mathcal{L}$ is the KKT matrix, which will be invertible due to strong convexity. You can do the same thing to get tangent vectors for changing $b$.

To extend the result to the smooth box-constrained problem, just use a sequence of log barrier penalty functions to approximate the box constraint.

To extend the result to the non-smooth case, just approximate the convex objective function by a sequence of smooth functions that converge to it uniformly. You can form the necessary sequence of smooth approximations using the methods in the following paper:

> Azagra, D. "Global approximation of convex functions." (2011).
>   https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.1042.pdf

Comment: This looks like an interesting approach. My a, and b are actually smooth.

If I understand you correctly, to introduce the boundaries to my problem, I simply introduce the inequalities to the cost function using the log-Barriers, for which the same result should hold?

Could you elaborate why the above may not hold for strictly convex (as opposed to strongly)?

Lastly I if you know of any References/theorems explaining the above I would be really intested.